# python: interact with shell command using Popen

Tags: python, stdin, popen

I need to execute several shell commands using python, but I couldn't resolve one of the problems. When I scp to another machine, usually it prompts and asks whether to add this machine to known host. I want the program to input "yes" automatically, but I couldn't get it to work. My program so far looks like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def auto():
  user = "abc"
  inst_dns = "example.com"    
  private_key = "sample.sem"
  capFile = "/home/ubuntu/*.cap"

  temp = "%s@%s:~" %(user, inst_dns)
  scp_cmd = ["scp", "-i", private_key, capFile, temp]

  print ( "The scp command is: %s" %" ".join(scp_cmd) )
  scpExec = Popen(scp_cmd, shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
  # this is the place I tried to write "yes" 
  # but doesn't work
  scpExec.stdin.write("yes\n")
  scpExec.stdin.flush()
  while True:
    output = scpExec.stdout.readline()
    print ("output: %s" %output)
    if output == "": 
      break
```

If I run this program, it still prompt and ask for input. How can I response to the prompt automatically? Thanks.

Comment: Won't the `-q` flag help? `man` says `-q      Quiet mode: disables the progress meter as well as warning and diagnostic messages from ssh(1).`

Comment: @LevLevitsky: Well, not really, that only silents the warning, but adding to known host is standard prompt I suppose.

Comment: Maybe you would be better off using http://www.lag.net/paramiko/ instead of ssh subprocesses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're being prompted to add the host key to your know hosts file because ssh is configured for `StrictHostKeyChecking`.  From the man page:

> StrictHostKeyChecking
>
> If this flag is set to “yes”, ssh(1) will never automatically add host keys to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts
>   file, and refuses to connect to hosts whose host key has changed.  This provides maximum protection
>   against trojan horse attacks, though it can be annoying when the /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts file is
>   poorly maintained or when connections to new hosts are frequently made.  This option forces the user
>   to manually add all new hosts.  If this flag is set to “no”, ssh will automatically add new host keys
>   to the user known hosts files.  If this flag is set to “ask”, new host keys will be added to the user
>   known host files only after the user has confirmed that is what they really want to do, and ssh will

You can set `StrictHostKeyChecking` to "no" if you want ssh/scp to automatically accept new keys without prompting.  On the command line:

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ...
```

You can also enable batch mode:

> BatchMode
>
> If set to “yes”, passphrase/password querying will be disabled.  This option is useful in scripts and
>   other batch jobs where no user is present to supply the password.  The argument must be “yes” or
>   “no”.  The default is “no”.

With `BatchMode=yes`, ssh/scp will fail instead of prompting (which is often an improvement for scripts).

Comment: Wonderful answer in terms of solution!! Although I'm still expecting an answer from python stand point. :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way I know to avoid being asked about fingerprint matches is to pre-populate the relevant keys in `.ssh/known_hosts`. In most cases, you really should already know what the remote machines' public keys are, and it is straightforward to put them in a `known_hosts` that ssh can find.

In the few cases where you don't, and can't, know the remote public key, then the most correct solution depends on why you don't know. If, say, you're writing software that needs to be run on arbitrary user boxes and may need to ssh on the user's behalf to other arbitrary boxes, it may be best for your software to run `ssh-keyscan` on its own to acquire the ostensible remote public key, let the user approve or reject it explicitly if at all possible, and if approved, append the key to known_hosts and *then* invoke ssh.